# How can I invoke a SageMaker model, trained with TensorFlow, using a csv file in the body of the call?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a TensorFlow model on AWS SageMaker, and I want to be able to invoke it using a csv file as the body of the call. The documentation says about creating a `serving_input_function` like the one below:

```
def serving_input_fn(hyperparameters):
  # Logic to the following:
  # 1. Defines placeholders that TensorFlow serving will feed with inference requests
  # 2. Preprocess input data
  # 3. Returns a tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver or tf.estimator.export.TensorServingInputReceiver,
  # which packages the placeholders and the resulting feature Tensors together.
```

In step 2, where it says preprocess input data, how do I get a handle on input data to process them?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I wanted to handle jpeg requests.

Once you have your `model_data` ready, you can deploy it with the following lines.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(
            model_data = 's3://path/to/model/model.tar.gz',
            role = role,
            framework_version = '1.12',
            entry_point = 'train.py',
            source_dir='my_src',
            env={'SAGEMAKER_REQUIREMENTS': 'requirements.txt'}
)

predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', 
    endpoint_name='resnet-tensorflow-classifier'
)
```

Your notebook should have a `my_src` directory which contains a file `train.py` and a `requirements.txt` file. The `train.py` file should have a function `input_fn` defined. For me, that function handled image/jpeg content, but the pattern is the same.

```
import io
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image

JPEG_CONTENT_TYPE = 'image/jpeg'
CSV_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/csv'

# Deserialize the Invoke request body into an object we can perform prediction on
def input_fn(request_body, content_type=JPEG_CONTENT_TYPE):
    # process an image uploaded to the endpoint
    if content_type == JPEG_CONTENT_TYPE:
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(request_body)).resize((300, 300))
        img_array = np.array(img)
        expanded_img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(expanded_img_array)
        return x

    # you would have something like this:
    if content_type == CSV_CONTENT_TYPE:
        # handle input 
        return handled_input

    else: 
        raise errors.UnsupportedFormatError(content_type)
```

If your`train.py` code imports some modules, you must supply `requirements.txt` defining those dependencies (that was the part I had trouble finding in the docs).

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess input data by adding an input_fn which will be invoked every time u invoke and endpoint. It receives the input data and the content type of the data.

```
def input_fn(data, content_type):
    // do some data preprocessing.
    return preprocessed_data
```

This article explains it in more depth:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/tf-training-inference-code-template.html