# Preprocess input data before making predictions inside Amazon SageMaker

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Keras/tensorflow model that we have trained by ourselves which does image related prediction. I have followed this [trained keras model tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-trained-keras-or-tensorflow-models-using-amazon-sagemaker/) to deploy the model in Sagemaker and can invoke the endpoint for prediction.

Now on my client side code, before making the prediction by calling the Sagemaker endpoint, I need to download the image and do some preprocessing. Instead of doing this in the client side, I want to do this entire process in SageMaker. How do I do that?

It seems I need to update the entry point python code `train.py` as mentioned here:

```
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = 's3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/model/model.tar.gz',
                                  role = role,
                                  entry_point = 'train.py')
```

Other articles indicates that I need to override `input_fn` function to capture the preprocessing. But these [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581156/how-can-i-preprocess-input-data-before-making-predictions-in-sagemaker) refer to steps used if using MXNet framework. But my model is based on Keras/tensorflow framework.

So I am not sure how to override the `input_fn` function. Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: What about this link
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_python.rst#overriding-input-preprocessing-with-an-input_fn

Comment: This questions has a related answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775557/how-can-i-invoke-a-sagemaker-model-trained-with-tensorflow-using-a-csv-file-in

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and finally figured out how to do it.

Once you have your `model_data` ready, you can deploy it with the following lines.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(
            model_data = 's3://path/to/model/model.tar.gz',
            role = role,
            framework_version = '1.12',
            entry_point = 'train.py',
            source_dir='my_src',
            env={'SAGEMAKER_REQUIREMENTS': 'requirements.txt'}
)

predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', 
    endpoint_name='resnet-tensorflow-classifier'
)
```

Your notebook should have a `my_src` directory which contains a file `train.py` and a `requirements.txt` file. The `train.py` file should have a function `input_fn` defined. For me, that function handled image/jpeg content:

```
import io
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image

JPEG_CONTENT_TYPE = 'image/jpeg'

# Deserialize the Invoke request body into an object we can perform prediction on
def input_fn(request_body, content_type=JPEG_CONTENT_TYPE):
    # process an image uploaded to the endpoint
    if content_type == JPEG_CONTENT_TYPE:
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(request_body)).resize((300, 300))
        img_array = np.array(img)
        expanded_img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(expanded_img_array)
        return x


    else: 
        raise errors.UnsupportedFormatError(content_type)
```

Your processing code will depend on the model architecture you used. I was doing transfer learning off resnet50, so I used `preprocess_input` from `keras.applications.resnet50`.

Note that since my `train.py` code imports some modules, I had to supply `requirements.txt` defining those modules (that was the part I had trouble finding in the docs).

Hope this helps someone in the future.

my `requirements.txt`:

```
absl-py==0.7.1
astor==0.8.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
enum34==1.1.6
funcsigs==1.0.2
futures==3.2.0
gast==0.2.2
grpcio==1.20.1
h5py==2.9.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
Markdown==3.1.1
mock==3.0.5
numpy==1.16.3
Pillow==6.0.0
protobuf==3.7.1
PyYAML==5.1
scipy==1.2.1
six==1.12.0
tensorboard==1.13.1
tensorflow==1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
termcolor==1.1.0
virtualenv==16.5.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
```

Comment: I guess, for processing the output I need to implement output_fn()? Do you have an example?

Comment: hey @Stiefel I dont have an example of output_fn unfortunately, seems like a good guess though!

Comment: Thanks, output_fn was indeed the right guess.